# Relaxing conditional independent assumption

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose we have random variables Y, D and X, where Y is independent of D conditional on X (Y⊥D|X). If there is another variable Z=f(X), where f(.) is a measurable real function, my question is: (1) under what conditions can we have Y⊥D|Z ?; (2) do we need the sigma-algebra σ(Z) belongs to
σ(X), so σ(Z) is sub-σ-algebra of σ(X)?

This is crucial to casual inference in econometrics and statistics, where we want to know if the conditional independent assumption (CIA) condition can be relaxed.

Comment: If $f$ is measurable, $\sigma(Z)\subseteq\sigma(X)$ is automatic.

Comment: So, we have Y⊥D|Z at this time as long as σ(Z)⊆σ(X) ?

Comment: Suppose $Y$ and $D$ are not independent, but conditionally independent on $X$. Let $f$ be constant. Then $Z$ is constant and being independent conditional on $Z$ is the same as being independent. So the answer is no.

Comment: If f is not a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition to have  $Y⊥D|Z$  is that $f$ is injective. The sharp condition (if     $Y$ and $D$ are not specified) is

$(*)$   $\sigma(X)$ should be contained in the completion of $\sigma(Z)$.

If $(*)$ holds, then conditioning on $X$ is equivalent to conditioning on $Z$.
If (*) does not hold, then there is an event  $A \in \sigma(X)$ such that $0<P(A|Z)<1$.
Take $Y=D=1_A$. Then $Y⊥D|X$ but $Y $ and $D$ are dependent given $Z$.